# How to store checkbox values if check box is in foreach loop (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have List of the question and All question is print in a foreach loop. I want to store some question id in the database using checkbox.

```
@foreach ($allquestion as $indexKey => $all )
          <tr>
            <th>{{$indexKey+1}}</th>
            <th>{{substr($all->question,0,20)}} {{ strlen($all->question)>20 
             ? "..." : ""}}</th>
            <td>{{$all->option1}}</td>
            <td>{{$all->option2}}</td>
            <td>{{$all->option3}}</td>
            <td>{{$all->option4}}</td>
            <td>{{$all->answer}}</td>




            <td>
               <div class="form-check">
                 <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" 
            name="present[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$all->id}}"   
          id="defaultCheck1">
              </div>
           </td>

          </tr>  @endforeach
```

I have no idea where I put submit button and how to get value from a checkbox into Controller to save data.

**updated**

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'addq', 'data-parsley-validate' => '', 
'files' => true,'method'=>'post')) !!}
 @foreach ($allquestion as $indexKey => $all )
          <tr>
            <th>{{$indexKey+1}}</th>
            <th>{{substr($all->question,0,20)}} {{ strlen($all->question)>20 ? "..." : ""}}</th>
            <td>{{$all->option1}}</td>
            <td>{{$all->option2}}</td>
            <td>{{$all->option3}}</td>
            <td>{{$all->option4}}</td>
            <td>{{$all->answer}}</td>




            <td>
               <div class="form-check">
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input big-checkbox"  
 name="checked[]" value="{{ $all->id }}">
              </div>
           </td>
          </tr>

      @endforeach
    {{Form::submit('Create Test',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I Put Button like this no action perform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same functionality I implemented for one my project and it's working fine,please check the below code. I think it will be useful for you.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="{{ $employee->id }}">
```

**PHP:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
   foreach ($request->employee_id as $key => $val) 
    {
     $payrolls = new Payroll;
      if (in_array($val, $request->checked))
       {
         $payrolls->basic = $request->basic[$key];
         $payrolls->employee_id = $val;
         $payrolls->save();
       }
    }
return redirect('/');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, Deepti, can you help me to add submit button in this code

Comment: @brij Yes, you can add HTML submit button. What's the issue on that?

Comment: when I put Button after loop noting happen and when I put a button in the loop. it shows every row.

Comment: when i put  button  inside the loop it's show error. "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: If you are getting error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" with the following code
`foreach ($request->employee_id as $key => $val)` Try doing it like `foreach ($request->checked as $key => $val)`

Answer (score 0):

You Should Try this

**Blade File**

```
<form action="Your route">
@foreach ($allquestion as $indexKey => $all )
         <tr>
           <th>{{$indexKey+1}}</th>
           <th>{{substr($all->question,0,20)}} {{ strlen($all->question)>20
            ? "..." : ""}}</th>
           <td>{{$all->option1}}</td>
           <td>{{$all->option2}}</td>
           <td>{{$all->option3}}</td>
           <td>{{$all->option4}}</td>
           <td>{{$all->answer}}</td>

           <td>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" name="present[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$all->id}}" id="defaultCheck1">
             </div>
          </td>

         </tr>  
@endforeach
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**In controller:**

```
$present = $request->get('present');
dd($present);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="{{ $service->id }}">
```

PHP:

```
foreach($request->room as $val){
   $data = new ServiceForRoom();
   $data->service_id = $val;
   $data->room_id = $room->id;

   $data->save()
}
```